# HTTP get method in Xcode

Tags: xcode, http, methods, get

I want to upload to an internet resource 2 values

I have created a php function 
"http://resource/top/?artist=VALUE1&title=VALUE2"

But I have a little bit lost how to develop this on Xcode side

Many thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1):

you can take this as an example

```
NSString *post=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userId=%@&password=%@&device=%@&amount=%@",[Login retuserid],[passwordfield text],[Login retdevid],[amountfield text]];
        NSLog(@"post string is :%@",post);
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://203.217.146.44:81/POS/api.php?fn=cashRequest"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSData *serverReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        NSString *replyString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[serverReply bytes] length:[serverReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"reply string is :%@",replyString);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to retrieve a URL, some easier and some harder to implement. As a quick start, for the unexperienced developer, this oneliner should do:

```
NSString *s=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://url/..."]];
```

To do it the proper way (checking for errors, and not blocking your program) have a look at NSURLConnection, or e.g. ASIHTTPRequest which bundles a lot of functionality.